# DeepCopy Attribute Dict loses dot-attribute access?

Tags: python, attributes, deep-copy

Why deep coping Attribute dict loses dot-attribute access ?

Is there a way to preserve the access after coping ... btw the dicts I use are multi level deep AttrDict's ...

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self


class XX(AttrDict): pass



In [49]: from attr_dict import *                                                                                                                                             
    
In [51]: x = XX({'s':1,'e':2})                                                                                                                                               

In [52]: x                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[52]: {'s': 1, 'e': 2}

In [53]: x.s                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[53]: 1

In [54]: x.e                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[54]: 2

In [55]: import copy                                                                                                                                                         

In [56]: y = copy.deepcopy(x)                                                                                                                                                

In [57]: y.s                                                                                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-1faf550cffec> in <module>
----> 1 y.s

AttributeError: 'XX' object has no attribute 's'

In [58]: y['s']                                                                                                                                                              
Out[58]: 1
```

---

I can add method :

```
    def rebind(self) : self.__dict__ = self
```

but then I have to call it after the deepcopy call.. and will probably work for only one level..

Cant find how to do that in **deepcopy**()

Comment: I be the deepcopy implementation is recognizing it as a `dict` and simply creating a `dict`. Implement `__deepcopy__` for it to return what you need.

Comment: hmm ... but if you look at the implementation for dot-access there is nothing to copy !!

Comment: Becasue the copy doesn't have its `__dict__` set to itself.

Comment: @sten what do you mean? You have to return an instance of itself, deecopying all of it's contents. The key issue here being returning an instance of the correct type.